# how to focus an activity to its top elements

Tags: android

i have an activity in which, on top i have a image slider, below this a layout in the form of grid which covers almost all of my phone's screen and below this at last i have a list view of of size approax half of my phone's screen.(i am using scroll view to scroll elements)

so altogether they are nearly of size twice of my phone's screen.

now whenever i start this activity, the screen automatically gets focused to the bottom part of my elements. in simple words, it does not show me the image slider and upper part of my grid view, it just show the lower part of grid view and the list view. 
so i need to scroll it up manually when i start this.

i searched a lot but didn't get any way to focus it automatically to top elements of my activity. please suggest me how to proceed now.

thank in advance.

this is my xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.gehlot.nitin.kitchenspices.Main2Activity"

    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main2">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:id="@+id/viewPager"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:text="Shop catagory"
            style="@style/textStyle"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/back"
            android:layout_weight="1.0">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1.0">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:id="@+id/img1"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:id="@+id/img2"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:id="@+id/img3"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1.0">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:id="@+id/img4"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/img5"/>
                <ImageView
                    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1.0"
                    android:scaleType="fitXY"
                    android:background="@drawable/back"
                    android:layout_margin="5dp"
                    android:id="@+id/img6"/>
                </LinearLayout>
          </LinearLayout>
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:id="@+id/lv_main"
        android:layout_below="@id/img4">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this line to your direct child of your ScrollView in xml. It prevents the auto scrolling to bottom part.

```
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
```

Example:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:orientation="vertical">


                //children views

            </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

Comment: @neens do not use ListView into ScrollView. It causes many more complications. Use RecyclerView and NestedScrollView instead. NestedScrollView developed for problems like this.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your root layout in xml:

```
android:id="@+id/root_layout"
```

In your Acivity.java add:

```
ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout);
layout.requestFocus();
```